# Enlazar Consultas SQL Server y MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo que relacionar datos de una DB SQL Server y otra MySQL. Me gustaría poder hacer consultas varias directamente a las bases de datos sin tener que hacer exportaciones/importaciones de datos.

Con Access puedo  hacerlo, pero es lento, y el editor es tremendamente malo. Además, si es posible, me gustaría poder hacerlo en linux.

Estoy probando el DBeaver, pero solamente puedo realizar las consultas por separado (o no encuentro cómo enlazarlas).

Algo así es lo que quisiera:

```
select * from DBSQLSERVER.dbo.tabla_1 t1
inner join DBMYSQL.tabla_2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
```

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Lectura obligatoria

Comment: Podes crear servidores vinculados desde SQL Server hacia otros motores, para hacer justamente de esa forma las querys.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @fredyfx Mis disculpas, aunque excepto el punto 1, no veo el problema de mi post.

Comment: Gracias ronpy, esa opción también la había visto por el "Plugin" del MySQL en SQL Server, pero quería evitarlo, pues me facilita la vida hacerlo en linux, sin tener que solicitar que me instalen nada en el SQL Server.